# sharepoint 2013 search bar disappears behind Global Navigation

Tags: 2013, search, sharepoint-server, navigation

Would anyone know how to fix an issue in SharePoint 2013 with the search bar disappearing behind Global Navigation? I'm having users say when the browser window shrinks, the search menu hides behind the Global Navigation. Is there any type of responsive design that could prevent this from happening? Or is there a way to move the search above or below the Global Navigation so when the window shrinks, the search will just move below/above the global navigation?

Comment: Its a UI Issue and your html is not responsive.
Try using **bootstrap** for responsive design

Comment: Are you using a custom master page?